# Mailchimp CiviCRM Integration: "Sync Contacts" buttons don't show up on "Mailchimp Pull/Push Sync" screens

Tags: extension, mailchimp

When trying to sync CiviCRM contacts to Mailchimp or updating CiviCRM from Mailchimp, the buttons "***Sync contacts***" don't show up on both screens:  "***Mailchimp Pull Sync***" and "***Mailchimp Push Sync***".

I've got installed **CiviCRM 5.21.1** and I've tested it with **Mailchimp CiviCRM** extension versions **2.0** and **2.0.1**.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you link the relevant groups yet via manage groups?

Comment: Many thanks. It was the reason why the buttons weren't appearing.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the buttons weren't appearing was because I hadn't **linked** **the Groups** in CiviCRM with Mailchimp through "**Manage Groups**" funcionality in CiviCRM.

Once I linked them, the buttons showed up.

Comment: It was the reason why the buttons weren't appearing.